# Change made to a variable in a function reverted when that function exits

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and stumbled upon this "weird" problem. Here is my code :

```
part_1 = ""
part_2 = ""
part_3 = ""
part_4 = ""

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

import random

def random_part(part):
    for x in range (0,4) :
        part += random.choice(alphabet)
    print(part)


random_part(part_1)

print(part_1)
```

The goal is to create a string composed of 4 random letters. Now when i run this code, i'm expecting it to print the string 2 times : 1 because of the "print" indication in the function and another because of the print(part_1).

Thing is, when i run it, i have a random string and an empty line , for example :

```
bdgv

*empty line*
```

In other words, the first printing indication located within the fuction works, but if i ask the variable after the function is done, it's resetted to " ". 
What could be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`part += random.choice(alphabet)` is a *reassignment* of the local variable `part`, not a *mutation*. The string passed as a parameter is unaffected. Strings are **immutable** in Python, so you can never pass them to any function and expect them to have changed. You'd have to return the new string object and have the caller assign it to the passed variable:

```
def random_part(part):
  for x in range (0,4) :
    part += random.choice(alphabet)
  print(part) 
  return part

part_1 = random_part(part_1)
```

Btw, whether the `+=` operation is a mutation or a reassignment depends on the involved type's implementation of the magic method `__iadd__`. For lists for example, it's a mutation and your passed parameter would have changed. Obviously, for immutable types it will never be a mutation.